# Set property NavigateUrl in HyperLink on C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, hyperlink

I have problem with this `HyperLink` in `Markup` on `c# asp net 4` page.

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HlLink" runat="server"
    NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("http://.../box.aspx?v={0}&e={1}&l={2}", "y", "IC", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Eval("Mtl").ToString())) %>'
    ImageUrl="/Images/edit_icon.gif" Target="_blank"></asp:HyperLink>
```

The image `edit_icon.gif` is not linkable, why ?

This generates:

```
<a id="HlLink" target="_blank"><img src="/Images/edit_icon.gif" alt="" /></a>
```

How to resolve this?

Please help me, thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for the `<a>` tag to be "linkable", it requires the href attribute. Once you get that generating correctly from the .net hyperlink control, it will be a "linkable" anchor tag.

Example:

```
<a id="HlLink" href="#" target="_blank"><img src="/Images/edit_icon.gif" alt="" /></a>
```